# How can I create a horizontal line with <span> or <div>, instead of <hr>?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I can make the tag `<hr>` effect with the tag `<span>` or `<div>`.

I see in large websites the horizontal lines, but they do not use the `<hr>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-Br">
  <head>
    <title> H - Line </title>
   </head>
 <body>
    <hr/>
 </body>
</html>
```

.

Comment: You would usually use the `border` CSS attribute, namely `border-bottom`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use any other HTML tag, define it as follows:

```
span{
   display:block;
   width:100% /*or whatever width you want the effect of <hr>*/
   border-top: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

Note you could use border-bottom or border-top and make it any color you want (#ccc resembles the hairline tag pretty well)

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

First, `<hr>` can be styled with CSS.

```
hr {
    height: 12px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Code above courtesy of CSS-Tricks.com. [See more examples](https://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/).

Whenever possible, you should stick to horizontal rules for their semantic value. Simply because "large websites" don't use `hr` tags doesn't mean it's the wrong thing to do, especially since the reasons they don't use them are unknown.

If you want to avoid using `<hr>` tags,  then consider [CSS `border` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a good question.
First of all, you could use hr, then style it. If this is no help, what about a svg?
I looked at a codepen and this is the best code i could get, you could edit the color and everything, this is just basics.

```css
.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1120;
/*   stroke-dashoffset: 800; */
  animation: draw1 1s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes draw1 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1120;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2240;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="line_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1200px" height="5px" xml:space="preserve">
  <path class="path2" fill="#01a09e" stroke-width="3" stroke="#01a09e" d="M0 0 l1120 0"/>
</svg>
```

Also - this has a slight animation to it, remove this with 'keyframes' in the css.
Hope i helped,
one way i've used for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I use a div as it behaves like anHR (they're both block). Then there are two routes. The first is giving the div an height of 1px (or 2 or 3, what you like) and add a margin. The other is a height of 0 with a border.

```css
.hr1 {
    height: 1px;
    background: blue;
}

.hr2 {
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p>some text</p>
<div class="hr1"></div>
<p>some text</p>
<div class="hr2"></div>
<p>some text</p>
```

The fun part is that you can add all kinds of tricks now. You can use a gradient, add shadows, transform them a bit. It offers a lot of room for creativity

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS to the `span` tag:

```
span {
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(0, 102, 255);
}
```